# how to get date from a form submission

Tags: javascript, date, meteor, simple-schema

I'm working on a class app in meteor that you take the class then take a test. If you pass the test, you get a certificate. I am having issues with getting the pass date on the certificate.

```
import moment from 'moment';

Template.SingleCertificate.helpers({
    passDate: function(){
        const id = FlowRouter.getParam('id');
        const classC = ClassC.findOne({_id:id});
    }
});


export const ClassC = new Mongo.Collection('classc');

ClassCSchema = new SimpleSchema({
    passDate: {
        type: Date,
        optional: true
}
```

This code displays the current date and not the date the test was passed. The date is stored in the DB in the collection (schema). 
How can I change this code to retrieve the tests pass date instead of the current date?

Comment: If i understand, you want to know how to use the Mongo database to insert and find data ? PS: SimpleSchema is not a collection but a package used to verify schema.

Comment: I think you need to provide more info. When you call Template.instance().data, you are trying to retrieve the data of the SingleCertificate template, and I suppose that's not the template where you had the class content. On your class content template, I suppose you are submitting the data, and you need to make sure that on submit, this data is being stored on the database (namely on a Collection). Then on Template.SingleCertificate helpers, instead of retrieving the data from the template, you shoudl retrieve it from the Collection where the data was stored. If you post mode code I can help.

Comment: @RicardoPesciotta I am trying to collect the data from the collection. The code in the collection is:
    export const ClassC = new Mongo.Collection('classc');
    ClassCSchema = new SimpleSchema({
      passDate: {
        type: Date,
        optional: true
  }
I have changed the code in SingleCertificate to:
      passDate: function(){
    const id = FlowRouter.getParam('id');
    const passDate = ClassC.findOne({_id:id});
    if(passDate){
      return moment(passDate).format('MM/DD/YYYY');
    }else{
      return false;
    }
}
});

Comment: Please edit your answer with all the code that could help to resolve the issue

Comment: The code is edited in the question field. Now with the new format, when I console.log(passDate), I get all the objects from the schema. Which the pass date is correct in there, but I need to pull just that date to display. If I try to return(passDate) it reads 'undefined'

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer:

```
passDate: function(){
    const id = FlowRouter.getParam('id');
    const certificate = ClassC.findOne({_id:id});
    const passDate = certificate.passDate;
      return moment(passDate).format('MM/DD/YYYY');
}
```

I needed to get the certificate ID, then the certificate, then I could get to the data.